# CDI class explosion

Tags: cdi, decorator

With current spec (2.0) there is no way to prevent class explosion
problem like what we do with decorator pattern:

```
Cake cakeWithToppings = new ColoredSprinklesDecorator(new ShavedChocolateDecorator(new ToastedCoconutDecorator(new BaseCake())));

cakeWithToppings.delish();
```

Now to do that with CDI our options are create all possible combinations
of cake toppings(2^3 = 8) as class or with producer method with qualifiers which
will create problem of qualifier and producer method explosion.

When GoF decorator used there is need for only 5 classes Cake, CakeDecorator, ColoredSprinklesDecorator, ShavedChocolateDecorator, ToastedCoconutDecorator, BaseCake.

And [@Decorator](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/2.0/javax/decorator/Decorator.html) doesn't solve this issue as i can see.

Is there any way I couldn’t think of or is cake lie?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully grasp your point, but I'll give it a go...

I think you are mixing two things here - GoF's decorator pattern and CDI's decorator which is not quite an implementation of that pattern.

In CDI, `@Decorator` can be seen as a "semantics-aware" interceptor rather than implementation of GoF's Decorator pattern.
This means that it can wrap calls to underlying beans of given types while being able to leverage the semantics.
E.g. you can create a decorator which will wrap all calls to any `Cake`:

```
@Decorator
@Priority(1)
public class CakeDecorator implements Cake {
 @Inject
 @Delegate
 Cake cake; // this will cause to it decorate all cakes

 public void delish() {
 // do stuff BEFORE actual cake's delish() invocation
 addMoreChocolate(cake);

 cake.delish(); // this is the original method invocation

 // do stuff AFTER actual cake's delish() invocation
 cleanUp(cake);
 }
}
```

But you can also easily modify the decorator to trigger for only certain types of cakes - you can do that by either changing the delegate injection point, or simply by checking cake type withing the method body. You can also chain several decorators if you so wish.

I'd say CDI's decorator is meant to meet slightly different goals. You could in fact design a decorator accordingly to GoF's principles and then apply CDI's decorator on top of that.

Comment: the reason why i mentioned \@Decorator was to make people notice that it won't solve the issue. I mentioned to prevent possible confusion because of name. Correct naming for \@Decorator for me would be \@Wrapper because it does not decorate it wraps and delegates. A real decorator should be able to decorate which means wrappers should be combinable  with different order and numbers. 

Summary of my original question is there is no way to prevent class explosion. Can you suggest a way to inject a cake with any combination of three toppings without writing a class for each combination?

Comment: For example as i stated at my question with 3 toppings you only need 5 class but with cdi you have write this classes for toppings a,b,c: BaseCake, aCake, bCake, cCake, abCake, acCake, bcCake, abcCake. When numberof  toppings 4 total class(or qualifiers and producer method) number would be 2^4 and so forth.

Comment: Like I said, CDI's understanding of decorator != GoF's interpretation of decorator. It is quite usual that there are multiple interpretations of one well known term. Look at MVC architecture, everyone sees those components slightly elsewhere. As for the question about the cakes, it might be doable but not in a straightforward way. You would need a CDI extension and a bit of magic. I think I saw something similar over at DeltaSpike.

Comment: I know they are not equal, i never said they are equal in contrary i said it doesn't solve the issue a decorator should solve. I think terms should be used respectful to original meanings. Some people use mvc differently than its original meaning that is not a right thing either but that is different debate. What i wanna ask you is, can you direct me to a example of solving class explosion with cdi extensions?